# Calling HTTP PUT on OWIN TestServer

Tags: c#, rest, integration-testing, owin, http-verbs

I have been trying to implement integration testing with OWIN TestServer class and everything works except for implementation of PUT or DELETE methods.  The POST method code (which works) looks like this:

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
{
    var response = await server.CreateRequest(uri)
        .AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token)
        .And(
            request =>
                request.Content =
                new ObjectContent(typeof (T), command, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()))
        .PostAsync();

    Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, expectedStatusCode);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

To do a PUT request, I have tried both of the following:

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
{
    var response = await server.CreateRequest(uri)
        .AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token)
        .And(
            request =>
                request.Content =
                new ObjectContent(typeof (T), command, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()))
        .And(request => request.Method =  = HttpMethod.Put)
        .PostAsync();

    Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, expectedStatusCode);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

and

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
{
    var response = await server.CreateRequest(uri)
        .AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token)
        .And(
            request =>
                request.Content =
                new ObjectContent(typeof (T), command, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()))
        .And(request => request.Method =  = HttpMethod.Put)
        .SendAsync("PUT");

    Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, expectedStatusCode);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The **SendAsync("PUT")** comes back as an unsupported method.  The parameter is not optional.  The **PostAsync** method ignores the **HTTPMethod.Put** and still attempts a POST verb.

How can I use these and other verbs other than POST and GET?

Answer (score 7):

As it would be, I found the problem minutes after asking this question.  The problem ended up to be a route issue.  By looking closer at the response, I was able to determine that the "405 - Method Not Allowed" had nothing to do with the format of the call, but rather that my route was incorrect.

For anyone else browsing, the correct syntax would be just **SendAsync("PUT")**.  The **.And(request => request.Method =  = HttpMethod.Put)** is not even necessary...